# check a string if have a word

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have a string like this:
    "TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,2;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,5;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,12;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,12;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.WordTOFIND,18"

I have a list of array with that, but some dont have that `wordtofind`.

My question is - how can I compare the string to check if have that word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool contains = str.ToLower().Contains("wordtofind")` i think...

Comment: Its right... I was doing toupper the first, and not the second .. now works well with contain

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably do:

```
string input = "TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,2;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,5;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,12;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,12;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.WordTOFIND,18";
bool stringContainsWord = input.IndexOf("wordtofind", 
                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a loop through your array and test if each element/string contains the value.

```
String input = "TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,2;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,5;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,12;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.Point,12;TEST.DATA.Data.COR.WordTOFIND,18";
if ( input.Contains("WordTOFIND") == true)
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: IndexOf is better because then you don't have to split/parse the string first into smaller strings

Comment: @PoweRoy i thought that the values are already in a List<String>, but if they're only one string you're correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `string.Contains` method.

```
bool containsWord = "[...]WordTOFIND[...]".Contains("WordTOFIND");
```

For example, if you are trying to find the elements in your list that contain "WordTOFIND" you could do:

```
IList<string> myList = ...

var result = myList.Where(s=>s.Contains("WordTOFIND"));
```